# Use package listing error: Listing.sty not found

Tags: listings, miktex, texmaker, windows

I want to use the listings package, but every time I compile my document in Texmaker I get the following error:

!LaTeX Error: File `listings.sty' not found.

Before this happens Texmaker displays me a window asking me to install listings, but even though I click install, the problem persists.

Comment: Do you have MikTex installed? TexMaker it self won't do the trick.
You need the packages to run your document...

Comment: I guess you use Miktex. Choose another server as source instead. I encounter that problem sometimes because some server was shut down.

Comment: @selwyndd21 I tried with several servers; But the problem remains

Comment: @Madhujith what version of MikTeX do you have?

Comment: @masu MikTex 2.9

Comment: @Madhujith Press `<Win> + R`, and type `mpm` to start MikTeX Package Manager. You can install the `listings` package in mpm manually.

Comment: @Madhujith Congrs, and hope you will enjoy LaTeX. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> LaTeX Error: File `listings.sty' not found.

This error message means the source file needs the package `listings` but the system doesn't have it. MikTeX was designed to be a TeX distribution that can install missing packages automatically, but this feature doesn't work well.

Fortunately, you can install packages manually in three steps:

1. Press `<Win> + R` to open Startup window.
2. Type `mpm` to start MikTeX Package Manager.
3. Find the package you want to install, and instal it.